# How does Pkg handle ES6?

Tags: node.js, zeit-pkg

I use *class* syntax in some of my node modules.  I have this config in `package.json`:

```
  "pkg": {
    "service": "./service/**/*",
    "assets": "./assets/**/*",
    "config": "./config/**/*",
    "options": ["experimental-modules"]
  },
```

When running `pkg .` I get this error:

```
> Error! This experimental syntax requires enabling the parser plugin: 'classProperties' (58:9)
  C:\dev\spectrum_service\service\thing.js
```

How do I do what it's telling me to do?